# Call Events on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am currently looking for events that I can subscribe to receive notification of call events (outgoing or incoming) on Windows Phone 8. Also if possible try to get outgoing\incoming phone number however I couldn't find any Windows Phone API for doing this. 
Is there any way I can do using C# or Native C++ on WP8 platform? Is there any Private API i can use to perform this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this for ages! Unfortunately, I concluded that it's impossible.
Really hope that Microsoft review this, and create a public class to access outgoing/incoming calls and sms.

It would help developers and the SO growth (with better and more interesting apps).